# How do you import value from a nested stack to a parent stack resource's dependson?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to pass values from my nested stack to the parent. I need to access the output from the nested stack in a resource's DependsOn.
This is how I'm passing the value from my nested stack :

```
"API": {            "Description": "invocation URN to be passed as env variable for ebs",
    "Value":  {"Ref":"ApiGatewayMethodPortfoliosPortfolioidVarProjectsProjectidVarFinancialsGet"},
    "Export": {
        "Name": {"Fn::Sub":"${AWS::FinancialStack}-API"}
    }       }
```

And this is how I'm trying to access the output in my parent stack:

```
    "DependsOn": [
"ApiGatewayMethodPortfoliosPortfolioidVarProjectsGet",
"ApiGatewayMethodPortfoliosPortfolioidVarProjectsProjectidVarFinancialsGet" : {"Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub" : "${FinancialStack}-API"}}},
```

I got an error saying that DependsOn requires a string.How should I be passing the values in this case?

Answer (score 3):

From the parent stack, use the `Fn::GetAtt` function to pull an output from a nested stack. For example:

```
{ "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "MyNestedStack", "Outputs.API" ] }
```

Comment: DependsOn can only take in strings so I do not know how to pass this object (thought about saving it in another property and then passing it). So instead of using DependsOn on the output of the nested stack I am now depending on the nested stack itself.